# Why does my python task not run with windows task scheduler but it runs fine in the IDE?

Tags: python, file, scheduled-tasks

This is the code in question. I have the task running with higher permissions so it should not be a permission issue. It has the sole purpose of deleting files older than a certain date automatically and above a specific size. I was wondering why it doesn't run when either scheduled or opened manually with admin permissions. It does open but closes with no prints nor deletes any files it should have if it worked. I also have already tried installing the libraries on path which didn't work either.

```py
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta


def Setup():
    Directories = open("Directories.txt", "r")
    dir = Directories.readline().rstrip()
    Directories.close()

    FSFile = open("FileSizeMax.txt", "r")
    FileSizeMax = FSFile.readline().rstrip()
    FSFile.close()

    Exclusions = open("Exclusions.txt", "r")
    ExclusionList = [line.rstrip() for line in Exclusions]
    Exclusions.close()

    lastDate = datetime.datetime.now() - relativedelta(weeks=1)
    formattedDate = lastDate.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
    return dir, FileSizeMax, ExclusionList, formattedDate


# Get clips in directory
def getFiles(dirs):
    list = []
    list = os.listdir(dirs)
    return list


# Delete any clips older than the last date and larger than the MB set in the FileSizeMax.txt. Exclude any thing set in exclusions file.
def delFiles(files, FileSizeMax, ExclusionList, dirs, lastdate):
    print(files)
    lDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(lastdate, "%m/%d/%Y")
    for file in files:
        print(file)
        path = os.path.join(dirs, file)
        print(path)
        timecreated = os.path.getctime(path)
        size = os.path.getsize(path) >> 20
        date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timecreated).strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
        parseddate = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y")
        print(f'{file} created on {date} and is {size} MB\n')
        if date not in ExclusionList and size > FileSizeMax and parseddate <= lDate:
            print(f"Delete {file} {date} {size} MB")
            os.remove(path)


dirList, FileSizeMax, ExclusionList, lastmonth = Setup()
print(dir)
print(FileSizeMax)
print(ExclusionList)
maxFile = int(FileSizeMax)
files = getFiles(dirList)
delFiles(files, maxFile, ExclusionList, dirList, lastmonth)
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? I suggest you look at wherever Windows Scheduler keeps its logs.

Comment: Your working directory is probably wrong. Are `Directories.txt` and the other files in the same folder as your script, or somewhere else? The current code looks for it in the working directory, which is not guaranteed to be the script directory.

Comment: @Chris Task scheduler gets an 0x1 error code. Which is supposed to be a permissions error but I have highest permissions on this user account and the task is set to run as admin. I have even tried to run it as admin from file explorer itself but it still just exits. I can try to specify a path.

Comment: Side note: Avoid calling variables `list`, `dir`, and other builtins. Doing so shadows the existing functions. That's not the cause of your error, but it's a good habit.

Comment: @Chris Thank you for the tip, however apparently the directory was not the issue. I still cannot run it for some reason. It runs without error still in IDE. It is just within windows it won't run at all.

Comment: You need to find the logs that Windows Task Scheduler presumably keeps. Without an actual error message, we can only guess (and we try not to do that here).

Comment: @Chris looks like I just didn't realize that the pip name for dateutil on windows was python-dateutil so it was a missing library on path. Now it works fine thank you for trying 
 to help!

Comment: I recommend opening a CMD or PowerShell window as admin and run your script from the command line. You can add more `print()` statements to help debug your code to figure out what is wrong. See [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for more tips on debugging your code.

Comment: I wrote that before seeing your comment to solve the problem. I'll leave it since learning these debugging skills will help you a lot in all of you programming. With that said, you might also look at `datetime.timedelta` class. This is built in and will do the same thing you are doing with dateutil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't realize dateutil was named python-dateutil when installing it so I just didn't have the library installed causing it to except. It works fine now. Minor mistake. Fixed it all by installing all of the relevant libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you can write a demo.py with main function, then try to call you API in your main funciton, and execute demo.py in cmd line, for example,

C:\python demo.py or  C:\python3 demo.py

You may find some clue.